# How should I setup my database to allow for followers/following like Twitter?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, many-to-many

I have groups on my website, and would like users to follow groups, and groups to follow users. I was wondering how does the following/follower works, in terms setting out in a MySQL table and referencing users? I'm very confused!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to do this is with two tables.  One table is just a list of users, each with a unique `userId` and any other information you need to store about the user.  The second table would keep track of who is following who by simply associating users by their `userId`.  It could be just two columns, `leaderId` and `followerId`, where both columns are foreign keys to the `userId` in the main table.

You can then get a list of a user's followers by selecting all the rows where they are the leader.

Comment: thanks great answer!!! but is this the effcient way to do it!! cud thier be a better way!!

Comment: @Solomon - This is the standard way to do many-to-many relationships like the one you are suggesting. There are some ways to optimize your database/tables to handle this, but you won't find a better implementation (in my opinion).

Comment: I am creating a table for tracking who is following who on my website, and this was a useful answer.  However it does seem resource intensive - say if each user is following 1k+ people it would get very heavy.  Still- its smarter than using arrays like someone else had suggested.